# Stuck in Flag_Activity_ClearTop

Tags: android, android-intent

I am stuck in the using the Flag activity clear top usage. It creates a huge problem to me. Sometimes it works and sometimes not. I dont wtf matter is. It is really confusing me. Please help

Here I go from Login Acitivy -> Activity A -> Activity B->InviteGroupViaPinEmailActivity-> on the Button click, I am opening a Alert Dialog and on the press of Exit button of this dialog,I am calling the following code.

```
   Intent userMenu = new Intent(InviteGroupViaPinEmailActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                                                       userMenu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                                userMenu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                                                startActivity(userMenu);
                                                finish();
```

For a while it comes on LoginActivity, But when I press back all the activities Activity B->Acitivity A again comes on, and then it is finally exited.

Whats the problem .Please help me.

Comment: either you finish all your activity A and B once you leave.. or override back in LoginActivity and onBackPressed just leave the app and go to home either using Intent or Exit(0)

Comment: I think you finish your Login Acitivity while you go to the LoginActivity -> Activity A. When you are using clear top flag then your Login Activity should be alive in your stack. Please make sure that you are not finish your login activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you finish your Login Acitivity while you go to the LoginActivity -> Activity A. When you are using clear top flag then your Login Activity should be alive in your stack. Please make sure that you are not finish your login activity.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Log.e("onkeyDown>>>>", "Called>>>>>");
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

android:noHistory="true" in manifest for activities to rectify all problems.Whether you tried?