# Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP in SherlockActivity not serving the purpose

Tags: java, android, android-intent, actionbarsherlock

The Scenario :

I have four activities : `A, B, C and HomeActivity`. `A` is my `launcher` activity. Am using `actionbarSherlock`, so A,B and C have `menu` option in the bar.

The flow is :

```
 A-> B-> C --**On submit in C**--> HomeActivity
```

Now when i press `Back` button on Home Activity, it goes back to `activity B` as after clicking Submit in `C` , am using

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );  //Shouldn't this clear A,B and C ??
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
    startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

But i would like to remain on HomeActivity  only as data is submitted and then it was started.

Also if menu button is pressed on `A,B,C`, then HomeActivity is started and in that case, i would like to have default behaviour of `Back` button(i.e go back to activity in which menu was pressed)

Any insights on how to do this as `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` not serving the purpose!

*(P.S. : HomeActivity is not a launcher activity)*

Comment: check my below answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you finish your Home Acitivity while you go to the Home Activity -> Activity A. When you are using clear top flag then your Home Activity should be alive in your stack. Please make sure that you are not finish your Home activity.

And also put this code onKeyDown() method in your Home Activity.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Log.e("onkeyDown>>>>", "Called>>>>>");
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

check more details check this [link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748857/stuck-in-flag-activity-cleartop/14749370#14749370)

**Other Way**

EDIT:

try to put above code into Activity A.

remove finish() method from your code like below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );  //Shouldn't this clear A,B and C ??
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
    startActivity(intent);
```

> And Most Important thing Don't Finish your Activity A launcher
>   Activity for Clear top method it should be in stack of Activity remain
>   present in your device.

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: There is no login activity stuff. Its just some 4 activities with Activity A as launcher which is different from my HomeActivity.

Comment: Simply change Login Activity to Home Activity. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Yep, there is no way other than making home activity as launcher. Thanks. Here is +1:)

Comment: sorry I didn't understood your question properly. but according to my knowledge and what I understood from your question, you just remove finish() method in intent as you shown on your question first.

Comment: and also try to put keydown method as shown in my answer in A activity instead of Home Activity.and let me know what's happened now.

Comment: As i mentioned in ques, my homeActivity and launcher activity were different and so the issue. Was looking for some way which could work in this case, but then, can see i have to make HomeActivity as launcher.

Comment: you can try my answer as I given in my comment.. it will be work. just try to put onKeyDown method in Activity A instead of Home Activity and don't finish your last activity and also most important thing don't finish your Activity A.